# How to mock.patch a dependancy in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock, patch

Mocking a method that is a dependancy is not working for me. When the method I need to test is calling its dependancy method, the real method is called instead of the mock version of it.

I do have the following files:

**myLibrary.py**

```
from src.myOtherLibrary import myOtherLibrary
class myLibrary():
    def __init__():
        self.myVar = myOtherLibrary() #dependancy

    def my_method():
        method1 = self.method1()

        externalMethod2 self.myVar.method2() #method2 called from the external class myOtherLibrary

        return method1 + externalMethod2

    def method1():
        return "method1 from myLibrary..."
```

**src/myOtherLibrary.py**

```
class myOtherLibrary():
    def method2():
        return "method2 from myOtherLibrary..."
```

Finally the Unit Test:

**TestMyLibrary.py**

```
import unittest
import mock
from myLibrary import myLibrary
from src.myOtherLibrary import myOtherLibrary
class TestMyLibrary(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('myLibrary.myLibrary.method1') #mocking this works because it's a sibling method from my_method() to test
    @mock.patch('src.myOtherLibrary.myOtherLibrary.method2') #this does not work because it's an external class from myLibrary
    def test_my_method(my_method1_to_mock, my_method2_to_mock):
        my_method1_to_mock.return_value = "something_to_return.."
        my_method2_to_mock.return_value = "something_else_to_return.."

        myLibraryVar = myLibrary()
        result = myLibraryVar.my_method()
        print result #I would expect to see this: "something_to_return..something_else_to_return.."
                     #But it actually prints this: "something_to_return..method2 from myOtherLibrary..."
                     #So mocking is not working for method2

        self.assertEqual('something_to_return..something_else_to_return..', result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Perhaps it's important to mention that myLibrary.py and TestMyLibrary.py are in the same folder, but myOtherLibrary.py is under different folder level.

I hope you can help me find what I'm missing here.

Any suggestion will be very well appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `patch` like that because the methods you are trying to mock are class methods not functions. So you need to use `patch.object`.

```
@mock.patch.object(myLibrary, 'method1') 
@mock.patch.object(myOtherLibrary, 'method2') 
...
```